# How to pass data from useSelector (redux) to useSate hook in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, redux-thunk

Hi i am trying to work on a app, which has some predefined code of redux, and react.
I am trying to get the players data which is formated json file and pass it to useSate hook.

The data which I get using

```
 const players = useSelector(getPlayers); // redux
```

looks perfect when I do console log, however when I pass this to useState

```
const [playerData, setPlayerData] = useState(players); //react
```

there is no data on the console.

I do not know if this is the right way to do, if not what would be the best solution to this? as I am more into react hooks and not redux.

any help is appreciated . Thanks

[image]

Comment: Hi, I would suggest you to use the `players` variable itself and not set another state inside your component. If you think about it, if the state was to be maintained in the component, then why would it be declared in the redux, right ? So instead of creating a new state, just use what is stored in redux.

Comment: Hi @TirthTrivedi, Thanks for the help, but  when I try to destructure I get undefined, do you know why is it so ?

Comment: getPlayers is a method? I need to see the redux structure. In useSelector, basically you have to do something like this `const players = useSelector((state) => state.playes)`.

Comment: Sure if you are a free for a remote session I can send you google meet link show the whole code please let me know @TirthTrivedi

Comment: Just send me the redux state structure if possible. A screenshot of state from redux devtools will also work. Can't commit for the remote session as of now :)

Comment: Hi @TirthTrivedi I have updated the code with dev tool screenshot

Comment: Okay, just use this code snipper `const players = useSelector((state) => state.players);  console.log(players);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246403/discussion-between-tapesh-patel-and-tirth-trivedi).

Comment: here can u pls share your reducer code.

Comment: could you please help me with this question if possible?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72967585/how-delete-an-item-using-redux-dispatch-and-react @TirthTrivedi

Comment: Do you intend to mutate the local `players` state only in this component but *not* in redux? It's not clear from the question *why* you want to pass data from a selector to local state. Also when is `players/fetchAll` being dispatched? Is the data available when this component is mounted?

Comment: Hi @timotgl Thanks for the help but I figured out the solution and mistake I was doing.  Really appreciated your response sir.

Comment: @TapeshPatel Consider updating the question with this info (and what the solution was) so visitors know there is no more help needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can set it in `useEffect` like that but my suggestion is to use the directly redux `players` variable.

```
useEffect(() => {
  setPlayerData(players);
}, [players])
```

Comment: Hi I tried this but no luck. And Thanks for the help as well

Comment: Hi when you console for `players` which value you getting?

Comment: could you please help me with this question if possible?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72967585/how-delete-an-item-using-redux-dispatch-and-react @kantivekariya